# ksoap2 equivalent to didStart/didEndElement?

Tags: java, android, xml, ksoap2, equivalence

my question for today is that i'm curious about if there is a close relative and/or equivalence in `java` using the `ksoap2`-library to parse element-by-elements.

In **`objective-c`** for example:

```
public void didEndElement(args....){

    if occurring element is thisElement
    //do something with the value in the element


}

public void didStartElement(args....){

    if occurring element is thisElement
    //do something with the value in the element


}
```

While in **`java`**

```
SoapObject foo = (SoapObject)bar.getProperty(enum);

aString = foo.getProperty(enum);

aNotherString = foo.getProperty(anotherEnum);
```

So, basically, what we want to do is,

improvised `java` syntax:

```
if(currentElement == "myElement")
aVar = valueInElement;
// or
a[1] = valueInElement;
```

I know that this might a be a lot to ask for, but any pointers or hints to where i can attain any information about this, if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SAX Parser can help you with that. As in this link: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

There, a class named MyXmlHandler is created. This one extends the DefaultHandler class and allows you to override the startElement and endElement methods.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {}
```

There are a lot of tutorials spread out across the internet wich show you how to use this method. The formatting in the link is quite bad, there's gotta be a better one to find.

Comment: On second tought, this link might be a better example: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

Comment: We succeeded solving this with another kind of solution, but since your answer was the only answer, i'll mark it as correct. Thanks for the response.